# Alternative for $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that validates the inputvalue with a regex.
Now I use $watch to check if the input value is changed, but due to performance I would like to try another approach.

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (inputValue) {
     formatter(inputValue);
});
```

The formatter function simply checks if the inputvalue is valid via the regex and calls $setValidity()

I tried to use $parsers but I found the value not directly validating when changing the input value, like this:

```
modelCtrl.$parsers.push(formatter);
    if (scope[attrs.ngModel] && scope[attrs.ngModel] !== '') {
        formatter(scope[attrs.ngModel]);
    }
```

Is there any way to validate the input immediatly after the input value was changed?

Comment: Have you tried the ng-pattern directive?

Comment: I did actually, but I use a directive to use it dynamically on multiple inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have custom directive for the validation, use $asyncvalidators

[Angular official guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

[Good article on how to use asyncvalidators](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/forms-in-angularjs/)

2. ng-pattern can be used for regex validation right away from mark-up